# Software to track and plan group rides

Tags: bikeroutes, maps, technology

Is there software / online resources / Drupal distribution capable of letting riders self-track and perhaps rank various routes around a location?

The end goal is to let new riders pair up with more experienced riders and let these folks share questions and advice on various routes in/out of a central location.

Comment: what hardware will your riders have? Garmins? iPhones? Androids? I think the answer will depend largely on this. Also, what research have you done already? Have you checked whether the common logging sites such as Strava, RideWithGPS, Garmin Connect offer this?

Comment: So far the only site that I've really liked it RideTheCity.com. But I'd like to have more control over the maps and allow users to browse through existing routes. It's not so much GPS tracking but more "this street vs that street." Or I didn't like this stretch of my commute, what other could I use.

Comment: Seems very similar to a message that got spammed to every riding message board on the internet over the weekend. Was for Ridely an app in the StartUp Weekend App competition. Not spam how its worded here though.

Comment: DW, I'm not spaming. I work at a college campus. Our bike to work week is coming in June, and we'd like to help new-cyclists map out potential routes and ask advice from more seasoned riders. I've been asked to find out what others are doing.

Comment: mapmyride, meetup, strava, there are quite a few avenues already available.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because software is off topic for this stack.  Please ask your question on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ and use the Cycling tag.

Answer (score 1):

Our club has a group on Strava where we can discuss various trails/segments. Outside of that we use Facebook groups and a forum on our website to setup group rides or getting people together.

I don't know of anything that would allow you to simultaneously compare a rider's data and then match up riders based on similar ability (or the other way to get experienced riders helping newbies). This sounds like a good opportunity for someone to make something!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use software (like Strava, RunKeeper, etc.) as @PeteH mentioned to map a ride and discuss/comment the route on the dashboard afterwards.

But you can also just trace a route on GoogleMaps and discuss it on a simple blogging platform.